# Блокировка много кратного запуска функции по время ее выполнения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени! Такая проблема - есть функция:

```
 function gosetbuttons (id) {
 ...
 }
```

запускается она через событие onclick в нескольких кнопках, я хочу сделать так что бы при запуски функции, пока она не закончит свою работу сделать ее не активной для запуска (в теле функции есть сегмент кода который работает а аякс - если это критично)

как вариант придумал сделать глобальную переменную например:

```
var blockf = false;
```

и задействовать ее как переключатель

```
 function gosetbuttons (id) {
   if (blockf == false) {
   blockf = true;

 ...

   blockf = false;
   }
 }
```

Подойдет ли такой способ, не будет ли от него глюков и есть ли какая то более правильная альтернатива?

Comment: а почему не сделать кнопке отдельный класс к примеру `.disabled`? зачем такие вещи вообще в js городить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тот самый случай, когда стоит использовать замыкание, чтоб избавиться от глобальной переменной -

```js
gosetbuttons = (()=>{
 let blockf;
 return id => {
  if (blockf) console.log('blocked', id);
  else {
   console.log('start', id);
   blockf = true;
   setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log('end', id);
    blockf = false;
   },999);
  }
 }
})();
 
let i=0;
setInterval(() => gosetbuttons(i++),333)
```